# ввод только double в командную строку

Tags: c++, qt

В общем столкнулся с такой проблемой, как ввод числа в консоли. Так вышло что консоль, выводит числа не совсем корректно как хотелось бы. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
либо 
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чистом Qt я бы запихнул "ввод" в QString а там уже обработал. НО std::cin  не поддерживает QString. Конечно можно задать char[256] и его обработать, но он имеет конечный размер  и это очень печально ;_: ибо я хочу сделать все **правильно**,
или лучше через  char[256] и при достижении в размера char-а более 256 сказать пользователю что он не имеет права в водить большее число ???

Я бы даже сказал как **принято** в таких ситуациях поступать ??

*вот код но он по сути не совсем о вопросе (просто для галочки добавил ) :*

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    double A_d = 0;    
    double B_d = 0;

    QTextStream outStream(stdout);
    outStream.setCodec(QTextCodec::codecForName("cp866"));

    outStream << QString("Введите первую сторону треугольника: \n А = ") << flush;

    while(!(std::cin >> A_d)){   
        outStream << QString("Ошибка ввода, пожалуйста введите число заново.") << flush;
        std::cin.clear();  
        std::fflush(stdin);    
    }

    outStream << QString(" Мы тут !!! ") << flush;
    outStream << A_d << flush;

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Не скажу про `QString`, не знаю, хотя мне и кажется странным, что разработчики могли не написать для него соответствующие функции... Но кто мешает работать со строкой `string`? почему сразу крайность - `char[]`?

Comment: Вопрос-то в чем? Требуется вводить даблы в шестнадцатеричной системе?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы же уже исплоьзуете [`QTextStream`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qtextstream.html) для вывода, почему бы не использовать его и для ввода вместо `std::cin`?

```
QTextStream in(stdin); 
QString str;
in >> str;
```

---

Даже если по какой-то причине вам нужен обязательно `std::cin`, то, на крайний случай, всегда можно читать в `std::string` и [конвертировать](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qstring.html#fromStdString) в `QString`

Comment: 0_о вот это поворот , я реально не знал об этом.

Comment: или перегрузить `operator >>` для `QString`